# Send a number on USB port using Arduino

Tags: arduino, usb

Any thoughts or helpful codes idea to program an arduino board to send a number on USB once a push button is being pressed .. so that a C++ or VB6 application can read the number from the USB port and do some task ?

The idea in a more clarified way is that I want to connect a matrix of push buttons with arduino board ( as inputs ), once a button is pressed then the arduino sends the number of the button which is numbered in the matrix as :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 . . .
```

Code sample

```
int inputOne = 1;  // as an example
int inputTwo = 2;

void loop()
{
If DigitalRead(inputOne, HIGH) {
 USB to send number "1"
}

If DigitalRead(inputTwo, HIGH) {
 USB to send number "2" 
}
}
```

So how to send a number on USB port so that a C++ or VB6 application can read it into variable or string ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino Due can be used with the USBHost library which will allow you to do this very easily. It will mimic a keyboard or mouse.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost

Then you could create a button array with a PISO shift register or use the MANY breakouts on the Due to drive it.

Comment: That's really amazing. You gave me another idea to simulate keyboard and mouse presses.. I guess then I can let the arduino to simulate numbers on keyboard .. And the VB6 or C++ timer procedure scans sent keys and save in a variable ... Or save/read a text file .. That's so useful answer thank you so much ..